# Strange image swap error on website

Tags: html, css

I have no idea how this is not working.

This is the image I try to add to my website:

```
background-image:
    radial-gradient( circle at 50% 50%, rgba( 0,0,0,0.46 ), rgba( 0,0,0, 0.88 ) ),
    url( 'https://picsum.photos/1600/1400/?image=630' );
```

From the beginning it looked like this:

```
background-image:
    radial-gradient( circle at 50% 50%, rgba( 0,0,0,0.46 ), rgba( 0,0,0,0.88 ) ),
   url( 'http://unsplash.it/1600/1400?random=9' );
```

Still I get this random picture when I doesn't even have the code anywhhere?

Inspect element when I'm in chrome(can't find my new code):

```
background-image:
    radial-gradient( circle at 50% 50%, rgba( 0,0,0,0.46 ), rgba( 0,0,0,0.88 ) ),
    url( http://unsplash.it/1600/1400?random=9 );
```

www.filipfahlstrom.se is the website if you want to check aswell.

I'm 100% sure it's the theme.css and I have saved the file and uploaded it to the domain.

Comment: What "random picture"? Please post screenshots illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is too vague to get a solid answer. Which file are you calling background-image:radial...ect  from?. How is not working, it the code simply not showing up or is it throwing an error in the console?

Here are some common errors of this issue.

-If that file is not showing up in then you are not calling your css file correctly.

-Try adding !important to your css which may have a conflict with your theme.css

-Hard reload browser and clear cache.

-Often when I make very small changes to my code and re-upload it to my server, it can take up to a few minutes for the server to realize the change and update it to reflect the changes when being served.

-Simplify, try rendering the images, before adding the extra styles. Once it renders, then get it to render externally, then add css to it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the actual background URL: `http://unsplash.it/1600/1400?random=9`

Each time you are loading your page, it gives you a random image (don't refresh the page... instead, go to the same URL again to see it give a different image) --- this is because you are providing a URL of a page and not that of an image.

Here's what I recommend--

1. Download the image (provided it's downloadable from legal standpoint) onto your local machine
2. Place it in your project folder---in an appropriate location
3. Modify `background-image` in CSS to point to the local image

Answer (score 0):

The image is shown correctly here. The problem on your side is most likely that the old `theme.css` is still in the browser cache.

The `theme.css` file is send with a `Cache-Control:max-age=3600, public` header. As of that the browser is free to load the file from cache for the next `3600` seconds before it does a check if the file has changed.

In Chrome you can see this in the `Network` tab of the developer tools, there you can see `(from memory cache)` in the `Size` column when it is loaded from cache.

While developing a website you can avoid this problem by checking the `Disable cache` checkbox in the `Network` tab of the developer tools.

Or use <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> to do a force reload.